# Safe to assume paymentState is absent from Google Play API for test purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

It appears when I get the [Purchases.subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) resource for a `purchaseToken` using the Google Play Developer API that test purchases do not include the `paymentState` property. However, real purchases seem to always include it. So is it safe to assume that when a Purchases.subscriptions resource does not include the `paymentState` property that that `purchaseToken` was from a test purchase?

We are validating purchaseTokens and renewals server-side and are looking for a better solution for determining if a purchase was a test purchase or not without having to depend on the presence or absence of an `orderId` which is only available to the app.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Did you figure out if paymentState is only available on real purchases?

Comment: Same here, seeing similar behavior and I'd like to know the answer to this question, too

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, after hundreds of requests to the Google Play API endpoint `Purchases.subscriptions: get`. The `paymentState` property was missing from every `Purchases.subscriptions resource` response

Answer (score 1):

since July 10th 2017, Google Play now provides an orderID from test purchases.

Comment: Please put this as a comment.

Comment: @dee-elle Thanks for that information. Do you have any official source for it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's relevant now but `Purchases.subscriptions:get` now includes a `purchaseType` in the response

`purchaseType` 0 means its a test purchase

Refer - https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that using `paymentState` was not the correct way to detect a test purchase. I noticed that if a purchaseToken had a failed payment, the `paymentState` property was not returned either. So we finally just settled on using the absence or presence of the `orderId` passed to us from the app.

Comment: But a test request (at least a subscription) also has an orderId. (I can only confirm that for subscriptions)